# CSS : 100% Width + Padding issue in android devices

Tags: css

on android the second div ( orange colored )
is shorter due to the previous div having a padding which probably makes first div..

```
100% + padding
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gz6kcgud/

```
<div style="width:100%;padding:20px;background-color:red;">in android this div is 100% + padding </div>

<div style="width:100%;background-color:orange;">and thus this div is shortened by android browser</div>
```

android obviously sees the first div as

```
100% + padding
```

that is why the second div shrinks when android shrinks it all together

( the whole web site is shrunk by android but due to first div being considered 100% + padding.. everything else gets shrunk also )

Comment: Then use percent padding or use `box-sizing: border-box;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's wrong ... The first `div` is actually expanding beyond the 100% width and the second one is actually 100%. It's visible in desktop browsers too.

You need to use a property called `box-sizing` that changes how the calculations of width/height is being done. Take a look [at this](http://jsfiddle.net/gz6kcgud/1).

For more information about this topic, read more about the [Box model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box_model)